# Woocommerce Min/Max, Default QTY and Quantity Step

Tags: woocommerce, code-snippets

I am trying to set the following for all products:

Min Qty 6
Max QTY 240
Quantity Step 6
Input Value 6

But all pulls through except the Default Input Value (product and Cart page)

Herewith the code

```
/**
 * Adjust the quantity input values
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 6;    
    }
    $args['max_value']  = 240;  // Maximum value
    $args['min_value']  = 6;    // Minimum value
    $args['step']       = 6;    // Quantity steps
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' ); // Variations

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    $args['max_qty'] = 240;         // Maximum value (variations)
    $args['min_qty'] = 6;       // Minimum value (variations)
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: What is the exaxt issue?

Comment: The Default QTY is still showing as 1

Comment: I have tested and works fine for me. What is your site URL?